# Is it possible to use an internal layer's outputs in a loss function?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, objective-functions, generative-adversarial-networks

For a network of the form:

```
Input(10)
Dense(200)
Dense(100+10)
Dense(20)
Output()
```

Those `+10` outputs are what I want to add to the standard `20` outputs, for my loss function.

Is this possible - in theory or even with some pre-existing library?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, and it is a standard practice. One famous example is the ["Inception" network architecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842). To keep inner subnets from "dying out",  several outputs from inner layers are extracted and passed into FC->Softmax. Then all the outputs are averaged in the loss function.

From practical point of view, you won't be able to implement such things with basic `Sequential` model construction. Most libraries allow you to move beyond it, though, and this distinction is usually well-documented. For example in the [tensorflow guide on functional API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) it states right in the introduction:

> The functional API is a way to create models that are more flexible than the `tf.keras.Sequential` API. The functional API can handle models with non-linear topology, shared layers, and even multiple inputs or outputs.

Hope that'll help you to get started.